# Excel Template Bulk Printing C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, windows, excel, printing

I have been working on a Windows application in C#. My Requirement is to print a predefined Excel Template with database values for a given Order Number. Means, i have to retrieve data from database(SQL Server) and replacing predefined cell values(Text) (in excel template) with database value.  For Example -

In Excel-cell value "SENDER_NAME" will be replaced by "FEDEX", "OrderNo" will be replaced by "1212" and so on. I am using following code to do that.

```
object missingValue = Type.Missing;

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

xlWorkSheet.Cells.Replace("SENDER_NAME", "FEDEX", missingValue, missingValue, missingValue, missingValue, missingValue, missingValue);
```

My PROBLEM is - When some values are not present in database for a given cell text in excel , its replaced by blank value, so it lefts empty spaces while printing. 
I have to cut down those empty spaces??

I just want, that empty space should not be visible into the print. Problem is that empty cell is printing as blank space, so for example AddressLine2 is not in Db. then it will look like following.

```
AddressLine1
EMPTYCELL
AddressLin3
```

I want the output like

```
AddressLine1
AddressLine3
```

Any solution?

Comment: What do you want instead of empty spaces? do you want to reduce the print area, leave the default values, enter new default values, or prompt the user for the values? The answer to this question will determine where and how to implement the solution.

Comment: i just want, that empty space should not be visible in to the print. Problem is that empty cell is printing as blank space, so for example AddressLine2 is not in Db. then it will look like following.
AddressLine1
<emptycell>
AddressLin3

I want the output like 
AddressLine1
AddressLine3

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNULL(expression or column, replacement value) in your SQL statement to get rid of the NULL values in your spreadsheet.  Replacement value would be ''.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Edited Answer:

Then I would suggest you build a delimited string in SQL and open it in Excel.  Don't use a comma for the delimiter - use something like semicolon or tab as in the following examples:

Semicolon delimited

```
SELECT 
CompanyName + ';' + 
Address1 + ';' + 
ISNULL(address2 + ';', '')+
State AS out_string  FROM customers
```

Tab delimited

```
SELECT 
CompanyName + char(9) + 
Address1 + char(9) + 
ISNULL(address2 + char(9), '') +
State AS out_string  FROM customers
```

By concatenating the delimiter inside the ISNULL function call, you will prevent back to back delimiters when a null value is encountered.  Use the ISNULL code on all columns where NULL values are allowed.

Comment: i am replacing values in excel, how can i do that for excel? problem is when value is blank, its get written to excel cell, when i print that excel in C# it show blank space there

Comment: see Pynner's comment above. I'm assuming your SQL select statement is output to spreadsheet rows. If one of the columns in the database is NULL then my suggestion can be used to fill in the empty space. So you would use ISNULL(column_Name, 'missingValue').  When column_name is NULL, 'missingValue' is returned instead of blank.

Comment: i just want, that empty space should not be visible in to the print. Problem is that empty cell is printing as blank space, so for example AddressLine2 is not in Db. then it will look like following.
AddressLine1
<emptycell>
AddressLin3

I want the output like 
AddressLine1
AddressLine3